# Play sound every x seconds if selectbox is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, timer, playback

I want to play a sound if a `selectbox value = 'x'`:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound/master/jquery.playSound.js'></script>

<select name="additiveSport" id="additiveSport" class="form-control is-invalid" aria-describedby="additiveSport-error" aria-invalid="true">
                    <option value="-">Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option value="Fahrrad">Fahrrad</option>
                    <option value="Heimtrainer">Heimtrainer</option>
                    <option value="Spazieren">Spazieren</option>
                  </select>

<script>
$('#additiveSport').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'Heimtrainer')
      {
        $.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724.mp3");
      }
      else
      {
        $.stopSound;
      }
});
</script>
```

That works, but I want to implement a timer function so that if `Heimtrainer` is selected it plays the sound every x seconds, and all other selected it stops the sound.

I thank you very much for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data-time` value number in minutes:

```js
var loop;
$('#additiveSport').on('change', function() {

      var time = parseInt($(this).find(":selected").data("time")) * 1000;

      if ( this.value == 'Heimtrainer')
      {
        loop = setInterval(function(){$.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724.mp3")}, time);
      }
      else
      {
        clearInterval(loop);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound/master/jquery.playSound.js'></script>

<select name="additiveSport" id="additiveSport" class="form-control is-invalid" aria-describedby="additiveSport-error" aria-invalid="true">
  <option value="-" data-time="2">Bitte auswählen...</option>
  <option value="Fahrrad" data-time="1">Fahrrad</option>
  <option value="Heimtrainer" data-time="1">Heimtrainer</option>
  <option value="Spazieren" data-time="3">Spazieren</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as i wan't it :) Is it possible to select by the name within the tag and set the value as time?

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as adding this would work:

```
//set a timer variable
var mySoundTimer = null;

//set the timer in seconds
var howOften = 12;

//add this inside your activation function
mySoundTimer = setInterval(function() {
 $.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724.mp3");
}, howOften * 1000);

//then use this to stop the timer
clearInterval(mySoundTimer);
mySoundTimer = null;
```